# Is 'slip out of my mind' correct in this context?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

Let's say my friend asks me to buy something form the grocery store but I forget about it.

> Friend: Did you get that thing?
>
> Me: Oh, so sorry, it completely **slipped out of my mind**.

Is the expression correct? Or should I use something else in its place?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your original expression would be understood perfectly but a native speaker would almost certainly say

> I'm sorry, it **slipped my mind**.

Comment: This native speaker would be just as likely to say _slipped out of_.

Comment: *This* native speaker notes that Google Books claims 95,800 instances of ["it slipped my mind"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22it+slipped+my+mind%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but only 1,780 instances of ["it slipped **out of** my mind"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22it+slipped+out+of+my+mind%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Personally I'd almost always use the former, but I don't see anything wrong with either.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The only thing I see "wrong" with "slipped out of my mind" is that I read it first as [slipped] [out of my mind], with "out of my mind" meaning "crazy/hysterical" and then have to correct myself, making it seem unnatural and making it much more distracting than the easier to read "it slipped my mind"

Comment: That hardly justifies suggesting there's anything "wrong" with explicitly including the prepositions. You can discard them in certain other contexts, such as *The dog slipped the leash*, but you certainly can't in most contexts - *When the police broke down the front door in a "dawn raid", the suspect slipped **out** [of] the back door*.

Comment: *Slipped out of* is perfectly fine.